# Saving Input form variables

Tags: html, coldfusion

I am trying to save form variables from my two date fields which are just normal `<input type='text' id="StartDate" value="" />` but for some reason when I dump the form variables using `<cfdump var="#form#">` it is not showing that they exist.

**Page 1**

```
<form name="generatereport" method="post" action="_location_queries.cfm">

<select name="Location" id="loc" multiple="multiple">
    <!---<option selected value="">Select location</option>--->
    <option value="OPERATIONS">Operations</option>
    <option value="CCC">Contact Center</option>
    <option value="QA">QA Department</option>
    <option value="DS">DeSoto</option>
    <option value="PS">Palma Sola</option>
    <option value="LWR">Lakewood Ranch</option>
    <option value="NR">North River</option>
    <option value="SDL">SDL</option>
</select>

<button id="add" type="button">ADD ALL</button>
<button id="rem" type="button">REMOVE ALL</button>

<textarea id="selected"></textarea>

<br /><br />

<label for="StartDate">From</label>
<input type='text' id="StartDate" value="" />

<br /><br />

<label for="EndDate">To</label>
<input type='text' id="EndDate" value="" />

<br /><br />

<input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Continue" />

</form>
```

**Page 2**

```
<cfdump var="#form#">
<cfdump var="#variables#">
<cfset date1 = #CREATEODBCDATETIME(form.StartDate & '00:00:00')#>

<cfoutput>#date1#</cfoutput>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The input fields need a name attribute.   You only have an id attribute.